# How to disable entire screen sharing and allow only application window and browser tabs sharing in BigBlueButton?

Tags: screensharing, bigbluebutton

Using BigBlueButton for online classroom I want to allow moderators to share their browser tabs or a particular application but not entire screen. When we tap on the screen sharing button from BigBlueButton Html5Client demo  then we got three options (Your Entire Screen , Application Window , Chrome(Browser Tab in case of other browsers) Tab) as Follows.

[image]

My requirements is to restrict the sharing of entire screen (From first option). Can I achieve it by customising some settings of BBB or by changing code of client demo application? 
I seen this [Disable screen sharing](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/customize.html#disable-screen-sharing), But this option is disabling all options.

Comment: Facing same issue ....if u don't mind ..have you got the solution for this?

Comment: You need to use either your custom share screen extension or web-driver.